# Does komodo edit provide a way to generate code to link a file giving the option to select the file (or graphic) to link?

Tags: api, hyperlink, code-generation, komodo

I need to move from coffeecup to something else because of a very long save time in a directory with 1500 files. Komodo edit looks good (because it is similar to what I have lerned) but I see no obvious way to generate code to link to a file and then have the option to select the html file from a menu tree. Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sample abbreviations](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/abbreviations.html) to do this:

- Go to View|Tabs & Sidebars|Toolbox
- Open the HTML folder
- Find the a element
- Click it